# How do I initialize a MySQL table that I plan to use as a key-value lookup?

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization, database-design, entity-attribute-value

SQL n00b here. So I'm making a table of configuration settings. The name and value of the configurations will both be character arrays (even though the values might represent numbers). I'll be like

```
                   wp_nas_configs
----------------------------------------------------
         name           |           val 
----------------------------------------------------
    "some_setting"      |          "yes"
----------------------------------------------------
  "some_other_setting"  |  "beep_boop-aslkj12202"
----------------------------------------------------
    "masteremail"       |   "bobama@whitehouse.gov"
----------------------------------------------------
          .             |           .
          .             |           .
          .             |           .
```

Each name will have at most 1 value. Is there a way I can initialize this table so that it acts as an O(1) lookup structure?

Comment: Basically you need an index on `name` column. Since they are unique your index search will end up after visiting the first node and then retrieve `val` from your table.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html
It would look something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `settings` (
    `name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `val` VARCHAR(1024) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`name`)
);
```

I use this a lot. In addition, I normally use additional fields so I can archive a setting (instead of physically deleting it), and another 'last updated' with a timestamp so I know when it was last edited.